# Java - Designing a set of Swing components and adding the set dynamically

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, dynamically-generated

I am trying to display attributes of an object (let's call it STUFF) in a set of fields.
What I would like to do is, for each instance of STUFF, add a `JPanel` and multiple `Jlabels` and `JTextFields` showing the values of the STUFF attributes to a `Jframe`.

My question would be : Is there any way to design a whole `JPanel` containing everything I want, use that as a model of some sort, and then, dynamically create an instance of it for each STUFF instance ?

(I am using Netbeans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a **Class** (CustomPanel) that extends **JPanel** and there you implement all your fields.

Each time you need to create an additional CustomPanel, you just write

```
CustomPanel cPanel = new CustomPanel();
```

and you treat it like a normal JPanel.. Create setter and getter methods to set and get values of the form.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that. Java is new to me so I don't have this kind of habits.

Comment: This is object oriented programming. In case you find this answer useful please mark the answer as correct so other may benefit from it.